Excel Function to interpolate a cell's value into the name of a separate referenced Excel file
I'm working on a model that involves pulling data from cells of a separate Excel file. In the referenced Excel file, each sheet is named by year. I'd like to be able to pull data into my model from the proper year depending on a cell holding the year I'd like to reference in my model. So, instead of pulling '[excel-file.xlsx]2023', I want to have the 2023 part be filled in by a separate cell in my sheet. In other words, is there a way to do string interpolation in an Excel formula when referencing another workbook?

Exactly what do you mean by interpolation? Perhaps you mean concatenation? You can certainly reference the result of a calculation, e.g. =INDIRECT("'[excel-file.xlsx]"&2020+A1&"'!B2") where A1 has the number of years since 2020.
